# Replacing to HTML Character Entities and reverting back

Tags: javascript, php, html

When replacing things in my chat room it comes up in the box as the 'HTML Character Entities'. However, I want it to revert back and actually show the character typed in when it is then shown in the chat room. So I am using the following code to stop any html from being entered and damaging the chat room by replacing certain html character with there entities (I want to get one or two working before I look at the others I know there are many more.) ....

### Javascript

```
                 var str1 = this.value.replace(/>/g, '&#60;');
         if (str1!=this.value) this.value=str1;       

          var str2 = this.value.replace(/</g, '&#62;');
          if (str2!=this.value) this.value=str2;
```

and then the following code then displays the text after it has been entered into the database etc. and on updating the chat box it uses the following to add in the the updated messages ...

### Returned from php and then displayed through the following javascript

```
    $('#chatroomarea').append($("<p>"+ data.text[i] +"</p>"));
```

I have messed around with this a few times changing it to val and using

```
     .html(.append($("<p>"+ data.text[i] +"</p>")));
```

Etc. But I have had no luck. I'm not quite sure how to do this I just need the HTML Character Entities to actually show up back in there true Character instead of displaying something such as... '&#62'

This might be something I need to actually put within the replacing code where it will include code of it's own on replacing such as (this is just an example I'm not exactly sure on how I would write it) ....

```
    var str1 = this.value.replace(/>/g, '.html(&#60;)');
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: PHP can convert this automatically

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#chatroomarea').append($("<xmp>"+ data.text[i] +"</xmp>"));
```

HTML [xmp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp) tag

The use is deprecated, but supported in most browsers.

Another option will be to use a styled `textarea` , To my knowledge these two are the tags that doesn't bother rendering html tags as it is.

Comment: I have tried the xmp method however now i am getting &amp;#60; instead .